# How Chrome App (not Extension) can read DOM element of page hosting app install button

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

For my Chrome App, I followed [Using Inline Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) guide, and when a website user clicks the installation button the app gets installed.

At the installation time (i.e. `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {})` in **background.js**), how can the app read a value (of DOM element or JavaScript variable - an ID of the logged in site visitor) from the HTML page hosting the installation button?
All online advise I found, is to use content scripts for extensions. The above-mentioned guide says: `"Extensions can communicate with the embedding page via content scripts"`.

What is a solution for apps?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable to learn how a Chrome App can communicate with a web page hosted in Chrome. As petewil-G said, though, a Chrome App will have no special relationship with a page that happened to lead to its installation. Chrome Apps are isolated from web pages by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't believe that apps are able to get to the underlying page that they are installed from at all.  The idea is that they should be sandboxed in their own private universe and not be able to affect anything outside their own window.

Extensions, on the other hand, are made to be able to access DOM of web pages.

So, I believe to do what you ask you will need to make an extension instead of an app.

If you just need to communicate some small piece of information from the web page to your app, look for another (out of band) method to do this.